# Asp.Net SQL Update Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have an `Asp.net` application on my page the user requests for a user to be removed. This then populates my 'Admin_TaskList' db.

An administrator then goes in the secure area of the site and enters the users name and clicks a button.  Upon the confirmation, the user is then deleted from my 'Users' db (already got this working) but I want my 'Admin_TaskList' db 'Status' column to change from 'To Do' to 'Completed'.

As I sad I have the delete bit working but I am struggling updating my other table.

**Snippet of code I have tried**

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE FROM Admin_TaskList SET Status = 'Complete' WHERE Description = 'Remove User' AND Name = @Name", conn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtRemoveUser.Text);
SqlDataReader rd2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
conn.Close();
```

**Full code**

```
public void btnRemoveConfirmYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PaydayLunchConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Users WHERE Name = @Name", conn);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtRemoveUser.Text);
            SqlDataReader rd1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            conn.Close();

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE FROM Admin_TaskList SET Status = 'Complete' WHERE Description = 'Remove User' AND Name = @Name", conn);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtRemoveUser.Text);
            SqlDataReader rd2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            conn.Close();

            txtRemoveUser.Text = "";
            Response.Redirect("/AdminSide/TaskList.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to close and reopen the connection between commands.

Comment: Better write a _Stored Proc_ and do both operation i.e. update & delete in that.

Comment: @RahulSingh You don't need a sproc, you can send a command batch in a single `SqlCommand` execution.

Comment: Why you using `ExecuteReader` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` for your `DELETE` and `UPDATE` statements? That does not make sense.

Comment: Also, use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteReader` as you don't have any SELECT statements.

Comment: @Dai - Yes obliviously we can I was just recommending for better maintainability, that is the reason I said _better_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using a `SqlDataReader` to update a value use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int updated = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Remember that you need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` on commands that modify your data like `Delete`, `Insert` or `Update`.

MSDN:

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for
>   example, querying the structure of a database or creating database
>   objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without
>   using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.

The complete method:

```
int deleted, updated;
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PaydayLunchConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    conn.Open();
    string delSql = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE Name = @Name";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(delSql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtRemoveUser.Text;
        deleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    string updSql = @"UPDATE Admin_TaskList 
                      SET Status = 'Complete' 
                      WHERE Description = 'Remove User' 
                      AND Name = @Name";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(updSql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtRemoveUser.Text;
        updated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling in understanding how to implement this.  I have only been doing development for 3wks so please bear with me. Could you provide what you are meaning please

Comment: @murday1983: have a look

Comment: Thanks but I get the following server error "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized." for the `updated = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();` line

Comment: @murday1983: updated my answer, forgotten to add the connection to the constructor of `SqlCommand`(the second with the update). I've also changed `UPDATE FROM Admin_TaskList` to `UPDATE Admin_TaskList`

Comment: Thanks.  I did notice this already and added it but when I did I got the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'."

Comment: Thanks.  I had already noticed I had 'FROM' in my update and when I removed it, it worked fine